# What does this Java construct mean - OneClass object =  ( OneClass )  anotherObject;

Tags: java

Sorry for the horrendous question, don't know how else to describe it,

I'm naturally a PHPer and i'm currently looking over some java and come across this section. The first line is just there for context, it is the line starting with QuotaKey that I'm interested in.

```
Key key = Keys.getKeyInstance( Keys.getKeyClass( cond.getKey( ) ) );  
QuotaKey quotaKey = ( QuotaKey ) key;
```

Comment: [Casting Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: Why the downvotes? seems like a legitimate and honest question to me.

Comment: If someone can give me a better title, or question words so it's useful to others - I'll happily amend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `QuotaKey` is a subclass of `Key`, you are looking at a cast operator that converts a variable of the type `Key` to a variable of type `QuotaKey`. You can write the same fragment more succinctly without a temporary variable:

```
QuotaKey quotaKey = (QuotaKey)Keys.getKeyInstance(Keys.getKeyClass(cond.getKey()));
```

This operation checks for the `key` to be of the correct type before coercing its type to subclass, and cause `ClassCastException` on failures. It is a good idea to minimize the number of such casts in your program, because their validity cannot be reliably checked at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

It's a cast, turning a `Key` into a `QuotaKey`.

[JLS 15.16, Cast Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16)

http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting

Comment: Thanks, and with hindsight, it's blindly obvious. I was looking something far more complex.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cast. It coerces the type of key into a QuotaKey.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is called type casting (in this particular case downcasting), it is just to use a variable of type `QuotaKey` with the reference of type `Key` which I assume is a superclass or superinterface of `QuotaKey`.